# SequelizeDatabaseError - Erro de sintaxe ao criar um campo do tipo ARRAY no Graphql com sequelize e mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, sequelize-js, graphql

Estou desenvolvendo uma API básica para blog em `graphql` com Sequelize e Mysql como banco de dados, tudo funciona perfeitamente até eu tentar criar um campo novo de keyword do tipo Array, para os posts do blog, acredito que seja algum detalhe simples, mas como não tenho experiencia, não consegui resolver ainda.

Erro:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[] NOT NULL DEFAULT , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NU' at line 1
```

PostModel:

```
sequelize.define('Post', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    photo: {
        type: DataTypes.BLOB({
            length: 'long'
        }),
        allowNull: false
    },
    category: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    slug: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    highlight: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
    keyword: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: []
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'posts'
});
```

Post Schema:

```
const postTypes = `

    type Post {
        id: ID!
        title: String!
        content: String!
        photo: String!
        createdAt: String!
        updated: String!
        author: User!
        comments(first: Int, offset: Int): [ Comment! ]!
        category: String!
        slug: String!
        highlight: Boolean!
        keyword: [String!] !
    }

    input PostInput {
        title: String!
        content: String!
        photo: String!
        category: String!
        slug: String!
        highlight: Boolean!
        keyword: [String!] !
    }

`;
```

Comment: Não coloque imagem do código e/ou erro, coloque como texto.

Comment: Boa! conteúdo alterado!